# jenkins Parameterized Trigger Plugin doesn't pass parameters downstream

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 jobs. I want the 1st job to trigger the 2nd job with parameters from the 1st job.

I was managed to have a properties file containing these parameters (key=value) and using the inject env plugin I was also managed to have these parameters are defined in my 1st job's parameters.

Now the problem:

I tried triggering the 2nd job with predefined parameters (i.e id=$id). That didn't work. The 2nd job got this parameter: id=$id (the string $id) and not the value of the id from 1st job. this although $id value is defined in 1st job.

I also tried giving the properties file as parameter. didn't work as well. got no parameters from it for the 2nd job.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dropdown "Add Parameters" just use "Current build parameters". This will pass all previously defined parameters to the next step. (Only those you added via Jenkins, not those you added in a batch script!)

Also there is in the same dropdown the option "Parameters from properties file" which in your case sounds like the better fit

Comment: I've tried "Parameters from properties file" (second picture) - did not work. :(
tried "Current build parameters" also - still not working unfortunately . I see the parameters in the parent job but they don't get transferred to the child job.
do I need to set build parameters (in the child job) with the same name as the parameters I am getting from the parent job ? (I've tried it just making sure..).

Comment: @Matoy Yes, that is exactly what you have to do, you pretty much just enter the same variables again for every step you need them in. Sadly every single one of these have to be changed if you want to rename them for example.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Jenkins are you running?

I encountered this problem today and it looks like environment variables cannot be passed due to a security vulnerability.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170

Workaround provided -

> As this change is known to affect a number of plugins, it's possible to restore the previous behavior by setting the system property hudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters to true. This is potentially very unsafe and intended as a short-term workaround only.